# Execution plan changes while executing parameterized query from application

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

We are working on SQL Server 2008. Java web application is used as the front end.

Each query that gets fired from application is executed as a stored procedure as shown in query #1.

We observed while executing simple `SELECT` and `UPDATE` query from application execution plan is different.

Query #1 takes 3 secs for execution:

```
declare @p1 int
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output, N'@P4 nvarchar(4000)',
                 N' SELECT KEY FROM dbo.DETAIL   
                    WHERE KEY = @P4',N'SIND-60068635-R-202'
select @p1
```

Query #2 takes less than 1 sec for execution:

```
SELECT KEY 
FROM DETAIL 
WHERE KEY = 'SIND-60068635-R-202'
```

We observed execution plan for both queries are different. For 2nd query an index created on `KEY` is getting applied and hence query response is good, but that same index is not getting used for query #1, and hence query response time is bad.

Any suggestion how to fix this issue are appreciated.

Comment: Both queries are different and hence differenet execution plans

Comment: made correction for typo. now both queries are same and issue as well

Comment: did you ran second query  through ssms ?

Comment: yes...it came out in less than a second

Comment: execute two queries in ssms and highlight execution plan ,then go to show exec plan xml and get these values and paste it in your question.

Comment: <ParameterList>
              <ColumnReference Column="@1" ParameterCompiledValue="(4)" ParameterRuntimeValue="(4)" />
            </ParameterList>

Comment: for query which is coming out quickly for that I could see this parameter list as follows, 
<ParameterList><ColumnReference Column="@1" ParameterCompiledValue="&apos;SIND-60068635-R-202&apos;"/></ParameterList>
For query which is consuming more time parameter list is not seen in XML plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing nvarchar to varchar has helped for getting performance benefit (index scan to index seek). Also as JDBC is creating this issue while passing parameters as nvarchar instead of varchar . We referred following blog

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2010/04/05/character-data-type-conversion-when-using-sql-server-jdbc-drivers/

Answer (score 0):

Yes,There’s a problem, When we switch over to using a parameter in Stored Procedure, SQL Server isn’t able to make effective use of the filtered index. To resolve this issue one way is to use Index Hint like

```
SELECT * FROM <Table> WITH (INDEX(<indexName>))
```

but for that we have to keep using the same index name

Other way is to use string concatenation i.e. by forcing SQL Server to see the literal value (parameter)

e.g.

```
 DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
 DECLARE @p1 AS VARCHAR(10)='test'
 SET @sql += 'SELECT KEY FROM dbo.DETAIL WHERE KEY = ' + CAST(@p1 AS NVARCHAR(10));
 EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Visit this url
 - https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/filtered-indexes-and-dynamic-sql/

Comment: thanks for reply tried providing exact index name ...but no result query still took same 3 secs time for processing. 
for second suggestion we will need to do code change in PRODUCT which is not feasible at this moment